String value changes when sent from HTML to JavaScript
I have a website and I am trying to make it so that there is a list of buttons and when you click on a list item it fills some text boxes at the bottom with data from an object, but when I click it, it fills the textbox with the wrong data.
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Records{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div style="background-color:lightgrey">
<br/>
<h1 align="center">Add Record</h1>
<br/>
<br/>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    // Get the checkbox
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("check");
    // Get the output text
    var text = document.getElementById("ex");
    var date = document.getElementById("dtr");
    var datetxt = document.getElementById("datetxt");

    // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        text.hidden = false;
        datetxt.hidden = true;
        date.hidden = false;
    } else {
        text.hidden = true;
        datetxt.hidden = false;
        date.hidden = true;
    }
}

function edit(noteid, ndate, ncid, nhours) {
    // Get the output text
    var day = document.getElementById("editday");
    var num = document.getElementById("editnum");
    var cid = document.getElementById("caid");
    var nid = document.getElementById("naid");
    day.value = ndate;
    num.value = nhours;
    cid.value = ncid;
    nid.value = noteid;

}
</script>

<form id="clock" method="POST" align="center">
    <label style="font-family:arial" id="datetxt" name="datetxt">{{ day }}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" onclick="myFunction()">
    <div id="dtr" name="dtr" hidden>
        <label>Date:</label>
    <input type="date" style="font-family:arial" id="date" name="date" value="{{day}}">
    </div>
    <br/>
    <label for="hours" style="font-family:arial">Hours Worked: </label>
    <input type="number" step="0.1" name="hours" id="hours">
    <br/>
    <label for="id">Charge Code:</label>
    <select name="id" id="id">
        {% for cont in contracts %}
        <option>
            {{ cont.name }}
        </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <br/>
    <div name="ex" id="ex" hidden>
    <label>Explanation:</label>
    <input type="textarea" name="textar" id="textar" placeholder="none">
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    <div align="center">
        <button type="button" onclick="submitForm('/home', 'clock')" class="btn btn-primary">Clock Time</button>
    </div>
    <br>
</form>


    <hr />
    <h4 align="center">TIMES</h4>

    <div style="width:auto; height:350px; overflow-y:scroll; background-color:grey;" align="center">
            {% for note in notes %}
            {% if not note.isquery %}

                {% if note.locked %}
                <form id="edit{{ note.id }}" method="POST">
                  <input type="date" name="day{{ note.id }}" id="day{{ note.id }}" value="{{ note.date }}" disabled>
                <input type="text" step="0.1" value="{{ note.hours }} (LOCKED)" id="num{{ note.id }}" name="num{{ note.id }}" disabled>

                <select name="cid{{ note.id }}" id="cid{{ note.id }}" disabled>
                  {% for item in contracts %}
                  {% if item.cid == note.mins %}
                  <option class="list-group-item" selected>{{ item.name }}</option>
                  {% else %}
                  <option class="list-group-item">{{ item.name }}</option>
                  {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>

                {% else %}

                <form id="edit{{ note.id }}" method="POST">
                <button type="button" onclick="edit({{ note.id }},{{ note.date }},{{ note.mins }},{{ note.hours }})" style="background-color:grey;border: 2px solid grey;">
                  <input type="date" name="day{{ note.id }}" id="day{{ note.id }}" value="{{ note.date }}" disabled>
                <input type="number" step="0.1" value="{{ note.hours }}" id="num{{ note.id }}" name="num{{ note.id }}" disabled>

                <select name="cid{{ note.id }}" id="cid{{ note.id }}" disabled>
                  {% for item in contracts %}
                  {% if item.cid == note.mins %}
                  <option class="list-group-item" selected>{{ item.name }}</option>
                  {% else %}
                  <option class="list-group-item">{{ item.name }}</option>
                  {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>
<!--
                <input type="text" minlength="30" maxlength="60" placeholder="Provide Reason For Edit" id="exp{{ note.id }}" name="exp{{ note.id }}">
                    <button type="button" onclick="submitForm('/edit-note', 'edit{{ note.id }}')" class="btn btn-success">Submit Changes</button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="submitForm('/delete-note', 'edit{{ note.id }}')" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </form>-->

                {% endif %}

                <input type="hidden" name="nid" value="{{ note.id }}">
                </button>
                    </form>
                </br>

              {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <br>
    <div align="center">
    <h3>Edit</h3>
    <form id="editing" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="editday" id="editday" value="">
                <input type="number" step="0.1" value="" id="editnum" name="editnum">

                <input type="hidden" name="caid" id="caid" value="">

                <input type="hidden" name="naid" id="naid" value="">

    </form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
{% endblock %}
</pre>

the result was that the editday textbox at the bottom had a date that the note.date did not, it outputed "2014" when it should have been 06-24-2024.

Please edit your code to use the rendered html so we can attempt to debug it.

Add the tag for the template framework you're using that defines all the {} stuff.

how do i use the rendered html this is my first post.

Use the DOM inspector to make sure the arguments in each element are what you expect.

Use View Source in the browser to see the rendered HTML.

every thing is fine until i run the edit() JavaScript function by clicking the list button, but i cant see what happens after that in the inspector. Thanks i wouldn't have thought of using the view source in the browser.

The problem must be that your loop is putting the wrong values in edit({{ note.id }},{{ note.date }},{{ note.mins }},{{ note.hours }}). You should be able to see this in View Source.

everything is filled properly except the date. it is stored in this format "YYYY-mm-dd"

Is the date format causing the error? Perhaps you just need to format your date as you're passing it to the JS.

We don't so "SOLVED" in titled here. If you found your answer you can post and accept it, or delete the question.

SOLVED:
when it set:
<button type="button" onclick="edit({{ note.id }},{{ note.date }},{{ note.mins }},{{ note.hours }})" style="background-color:grey;border: 2px solid grey;">

It used the {{note.date}} as a written input, so it passed 06-24-2024,
so it subtracted them from eachother, the solution was adding quotation marks around the variable and switching the encasing quattion marks for apostraphes:
<button type="button" onclick='edit({{ note.id }},"{{ note.date }}",{{ note.mins }},{{ note.hours }})' style="background-color:grey;border: 2px solid grey;">

